# How does Stack Overflow implement soft delete of post/answer?

Tags: discussion

How does Stack Overflow implement soft delete of post/answer? As far as I know there're two approaches to do this:

1. Add addtional "isDeleted" field/column to indicates the post is deleted or not.
2. Use another table to store the deleted records.( DB Archive)
3. Any other approach ?

Does anyone know how StackOverflow implement this?

Comment: Looking at [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), probably just by setting the deletion-date...

Comment: Deleted content is available to mods and 10k users, with a date. So there's a deleteddate column...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, the first approach. We have a `DeletionDate` column on Posts. When it's null, the post is not deleted. When it has a value, it's the timestamp of the deletion.